# Issue setting .text in jQuery .each

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm trying to dynamically pass a list of nav bar items into an unordered list. The list as is follows (shortened for brevity)

```js
i = 0
$('#navList li').each(function() {
  i++;
  var name = menu[i].name;
  console.log(menu[i].name);

  $('a').text(name);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto" id="navList">
  <div class="hori-selector">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- **LISTITEMS** -->
  <li class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link" id="nav1" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="far fa-building"></i>Test1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="nav2" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fas fa-quote-right"></i>Test2</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

My two issues arise when

1. as I iterate through my object of menu items, I can successfully console log the string text, but the jQuery .text function isn't working.
2. Lastly, I'd also like to retain the I tag that contains my icon.

Thanks!

Comment: There's no need to have an external `i` variable. https://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: Are you sure .text() isn't working? it's more likely that it *is* working, but your code isn't doing what intended it to do.

Comment: @KevinB it wasn't working unless I added .find like Pete suggested.

Comment: no, .text was certainly working, it doesn't just do nothing. It was setting the text of *all* anchor tags to the text you told it to, on each iteration.

Comment: I'm certain you're right, just starting my learning journey.  I'm looking into it deeper to get a firmer grasp, thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to find the anchor inside the current `li` of the each loop - to do this, you can use the each loop parameters:

```js
const menu = [{ name : 'test'}, {name:  'test 1'}];

$('#navList li').each(function(index, element) {    // change function to use parameters
  var name = menu[index].name;
  var $anchor = $(element).find('a');               // find the anchor in the current li
  
  $anchor.contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3;
  }).remove();                                      // remove current text
  
  $anchor.append(name);                             // append new text
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto" id="navList">
  <div class="hori-selector">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- **LISTITEMS** -->
  <li class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link" id="nav1" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="far fa-building">icon</i>Test1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="nav2" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fas fa-quote-right">icon</i>Test2</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That was my mistake!  You answer was helpful, I'm working through it now.  I will fix if I can.  I actually marked it as useful, but I don't have enough reputation points.